# Shutdown mode on stm32 consuming a lot of power

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, low-power, stm32cubemx, nucleo

I am testing the demo code given in the directory STM32Cube\Repository\STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.14.0\Projects\NUCLEO-L476RG\Examples\PWR for CubeMX. I am testing the code PWR_ModesSelection and am recording the current values across J6 IDD which I'll be writing down below.

For SHUTDOWN, I'm getting a reading of 3.84 mA.

For RUN Range 1, 80MHz with FLASH ART on, I'm getting 14.08 mA.

According to the document,  [an4621](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/9e/9b/ca/a3/92/5d/44/ff/DM00148033.pdf/files/DM00148033.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00148033.pdf), power consumption without RTC in shutdown mode should be 0.33uA. Why am I seeing such a high current value? Is there a drain due to the components on the board? I'm using [STM32L476RG Nucleo](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf) board and have no peripherals attached.

```c
void test_shutdown(void)
{
  printf("\n\r Executing test (SHUTDOWN) \n\r");
  printf(" Please measure current then use Reset button to select another test \n\r");
 
  /* Set all GPIO in analog state to reduce power consumption */
  GPIO_AnalogState_Config();
  
  /* Enable Power Clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  
  /* Enter the SHUTDOWN mode */
  HAL_PWREx_EnterSHUTDOWNMode();
  
}

void GPIO_AnalogState_Config(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  
  /* Set all GPIO in analog state to reduce power consumption, */
        
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();    

    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);  

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();

}
```

Above is the code that turns on the Shutdown mode for the given example. It's being called when a certain condition is being met in the main function.

Comment: Impossible to tell out of the blue. You'll have to show schematics, tell us how you measure and possibly also post the source code.

Comment: @Lundin Added the schematics of the board and the code that's running.

Comment: That's not schematics... and you still haven't told how you measure current consumption.

Comment: I've updated the document. My bad. I've mentioned that I measure the current across IDD jumper using a multimeter.

Comment: Vdd apparently supplies the whole board including pull-ups, USB stuff and the on-board programming interface. I'm not sure what ST were thinking when they added JP6. You can't use that one to measure CPU current consumption.

Comment: Perhaps enabling pull-ups/downs would help. Leaving pins floating can have detrimental effect on power consumption; there are many questions here about this topic.

Comment: All the pins are in Analog Input mode, so I guess leakages will be minimized by that?

Comment: @Lundin Doesn't the ST-Link programmer run off its own supply with its own regulator? I'd imagine most of the on-board pullups would have quite low effect on the power consumption otherwise

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I just looked at the linked schematic and they supply all manner of things through Vdd. It doesn't make sense to measure uA currents on something that supply 4k7 pull ups.... thats 700uA per pull-up.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to calculate the current on this board? @Lundin

Comment: You could lift the MCU pins, but it's not something I'd recommend in general.

Comment: ST CubeMX offers a tool to calculate power consumption with a high degree of flexibility, but that really is just a calculation, no real measurement.

Comment: @jusaca I've tried this tool already and there's a 5-9 mA difference between the CubeMX value and my measurement across IDD.

Comment: Well, as mentioned above, the measurement at the IDD jumper on this board does not make sense, I made the same mistake a few weeks ago. There is too much other stuff supplied via IDD. You have to get/make a board where you can probe the supply line independently from any other consumers.

Comment: @jusaca I see. How close is this value to the value given by CubeMX?

Comment: If the Cube tool is configured properly the result will be pretty accurate. But I actually never tested it.

Comment: @jusaca I see. I guess I'll test this out and post the result as the answer down on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

It takes quite a bit of effort to get a very low shutdown current, as almost anything causes it to be higher than specified - at 0.33 uA, the ambient humidity has an effect, so you can't even breathe on the PCB.

I suggest you start by running a really simple do-nothing program, that doesn't initialise any peripherals, and just shuts down. You must disconnect the JTAG/SWD adaptor that you use for programming, as that takes a lot of current - just power up the board in isolation, and hopefully the current should be tens of microamps or less.

Then gradually add code to start up & shut down specific peripherals, and you will discover which one is causing the current drain.

Answer (score 0):

The state of GPIO pins as you have configured them in GPIO_AnalogState_Config() applies up to Stop mode. In Standby and Shutdown modes, every  pin is in High-Z state. If you want to set the internal pull-up/down (in order to "fix" the pin voltage level), you shoud use a specific function, that configures the state of PU/PD resistor only for Standby/Shutdown modes, no matter the GPIO state in Run/Stop mode.
Specifically for STM32L476 ,check functions from STM32CubeIDE ( stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.h, stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c )  :

```
HAL_PWREx_EnableGPIOPullUp()
HAL_PWREx_EnableGPIOPullDown()
HAL_PWREx_EnablePullUpPullDownConfig();
```

and sections 5.3.9, 5.3.10 in Reference Manual ( [RM0351](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0351-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) )